# how to change a dropdown menu to transparent

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown menu and the css is `background-color: transparent;`

http://jsfiddle.net/6byBL/1

I know it is transparent here in chrome it is not. it is white. also in IE and firefox where the values are located when drop down is shown has a white background can i change this to transparent.

Comment: Can you throw a quick test case in jsFiddle?

Comment: @ShadowWizard jsfiddle.net/6byBL/1 i know it is transparent here in chrome it is not. it is white. also in IE and firefox where the values are has a white background can i change this to transparent

Comment: See my answer for possible workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Input elements are styles very inconsistently between browsers and platforms. Not all browsers will style all sub-elements of a input field.

If you are really insistent to control the appearance you probably want to create a replacement widget using HTML+JS. But beware that you could severely degrade usability, especially for screen readers, keyboard users or people using other assistive technology.

Personally I've just accepted that form elements are inconsistently styles and usually leave them styled by the browser. Then you have input elements that will in most cases looks like the OS controls. It ensures usability and the input elements are immediately recognizable to the user.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the browser rendering - you can't directly control this, but if you are willing to "give up" on the arrow there is a workaround by adding `-webkit-appearance: none;` as well:

```css
body { background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Fwcz.jpg); }

#colour1 {
    padding: 5px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<form> 
    <select name="colour1" id="colour1" width="100px">
        <option>Please Select</option>
        <option value="red">red</option>
        <option value="blue">blue</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: This only makes the initial select menu transparent, **not** the dropdown menu as was requested! I don't believe there is a way to currently do this since the dropdown options only support RGB (no alpha); please correct me if I'm wrong! (not a problem in Firefox)

Comment: @LemonPi that wasn't clear from the question and OP never replied to my answer. Anyway these days we have plenty of jQuery replacements so it's all not really relevant.

Comment: I'd like to achieve a transparent dropdown select menu (not using li, since those do not support multiselect very gracefully). Could you link me to some of those jQuery replacements?

Comment: I've been using [Bootstrap's dropdown lists](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) for a while, didn't make them transparent but pretty sure it's possible since they're actually using lists - as for multiselect I'm sure they have a kind of drop down with checkboxes which is good replacement IMO.

Comment: I see... I generally dislike bootstrap because of how homogeneous the websites built from it usually look. That and the fact that it uses JS for styling the layout (shouldn't there be a separation of concerns here?) Thanks for your input though.

Comment: Sure thing, feel free to join me in chat if you want further advice/discussion. :)